# Using "?android:colorBackground" as a color crashes my app on Galaxy Note 3 (4.4.2) but not Nexus

Tags: android

Is there a minimum android version requirement to access this color or something? I need to set the background color of an object to the 'default' background color and '?android:colorBackground' works well on my Nexus 5 (Android 5.1.1) but it is crashing my Note.

I have a drawable called editor_border.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- content background -->
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="?android:colorBackground" />
                    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>  
    </layer-list>
```

I use this drawable as the background for a layout. When inflating the layout, my app crashes with the folowing error"

```
10-07 22:23:52.634: E/AndroidRuntime(6512): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

And further down

```
10-07 22:23:52.634: E/AndroidRuntime(6512): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v4/editor_border.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020005

10-07 22:23:52.634: E/AndroidRuntime(6512): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
```

Removing the color or changing it to any other color works fine.

Comment: post the logcat for error. where is it crashing? little code would be helpful

Comment: Done - more details provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom attributes in drawable resource seem to only work from API 21. I can't find the source to back this up but [a commit](https://github.com/google/iosched/commit/dd7ed72a7eb2d223203db079bd99d31c6ef3061e) from Google I/O Schedule app demonstrates this.

A workaround would be to have 2 different drawable resources, one for API 21+ and another one pre-21, in which you should not use custom attributes.

**drawable/background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- content background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/your_color" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>  
</layer-list>
```

**drawable-v21/background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- content background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="?android:colorBackground" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>  
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Great reply, though this sort of throws me into the deep end again because the point was to match the background color of the current theme (Device default). This changes based on device. Hard coding a color value means that my background color won't change according to the theme.

Comment: In that case you would have to use different drawables (which hardcode different colors) per theme then. I actually discover this when trying to support dynamic theme in my app.

Comment: But every vendor has a different theme - Samsungs galaxy line, the nexus line, xperia line.. etc! I guess I just hardcode a color for these 'older devices'? (Pre 21)